# Format time in Angular

Tags: angularjs, time, format

I have a time field coming from the database that is formated like "14:37:39". I need it formated to be like "2:37 PM".  I have tried to use the date filter (which formats time as well), but with no luck.

Help!

```
<span class="time">{{ feeding.time | date: "shortTime" }}</span>
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: Is 'feeding.time' a date object or a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your own filter based on the format you're expecting...

```
angular.module('foo', [])
.filter('formatTime', function ($filter) {
    return function (time) {
        var parts = time.split(':');
        var date = new Date(0, 0, 0, parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
        return $filter('date')(date, 'h:mm a');
    };
});
```

---

```
{{ '14:37:39' | formatTime }}
```

Outputs `2:37 PM`

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zyqLu7nd/)

Comment: He was faster than me! +1 ;)

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks.

Comment: @Mechwd Actually you don't need to splet the 'time' for creating the date you could do this instead: var date = new Date("0001-01-01" + time);

Comment: How would I do that from the array, when the ng-repeat is pulling right from the array. Sorry I'm a js and angular noob.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Where's the ng-repeat?

Comment: Sorry,

    <li ng-repeat="feeding in feedings.entry">
      <a href="">
        <span class="time">{{ feeding.time | formatTime }}</span>
        <span class="amount">{{ feeding.amount }} oz.</span>
      </a>
    </li>

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is that `feeding.time` is a string and the `date` filter is expecting a date.

Comment: ok that makes sense. Is there a way to turn the string into a date object?

Comment: @Mechwd yes, of course, give me a sec I will update the answer in a moment.